# DESKTOP COLOR FIX when yellow

Tags: desktop-environments

how to fix colors on desktop? Monitor buttons didn't affect it. And looks all yellow, no white colors anymore.

Comment: Take a screenshot and link to it in your question. If it looks yellow to us, it's the OS. If it looks normal, you need to check your monitor cable.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is a problem with your monitor cable, not with the OS. Check to make sure your monitor cable is securely plugged in.  If you are using a desktop computer, try using a different cable to connect your monitor to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **VGA/HDMI** cable to see if it's plugged in and/or screwed properly, both at the CPU end and on the monitor's end. You can try interchanging the sides of the cable, putting the ends vice versa.

If that doesn't work, you might need to replace your cable. However, before doing that, try switching with another cable from another computer to see if the problem is with the cable's connections, or with either the CPU or Monitor port on which it connects.